# Laravel Controller to Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I've built a website using Laravel that I'm happy with, however, due to not planning ahead I have built the admin/management panel, and now that I have to go through and do the user front end I'm wondering how I should have though to handle this.

Currently I have a **web.php** file containing lines like this:

```
# WEDDING HANDLING
Route::get('/admin/weddings', 'WeddingController@index');
Route::get('/admin/wedding/create', 'WeddingController@create');
Route::get('/admin/wedding/{wedding}', 'WeddingController@show');
Route::get('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/edit', 'WeddingController@edit');

Route::post('/admin/wedding/create', 'WeddingController@store');
Route::put('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/edit', 'WeddingController@update');
Route::delete('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/destroy', 'WeddingController@destroy');

# MENU HANDLING
Route::get('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/menus', 'MenuController@index');
Route::get('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/menu/create', 'MenuController@create');
Route::get('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/menu/{menu}', 'MenuController@show');
Route::get('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/menu/{menu}/edit', 'MenuController@edit');

Route::post('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/menu/create', 'MenuController@store');
Route::put('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/menu/{menu}/edit', 'MenuController@update');
Route::delete('/admin/wedding/{wedding}/menu/{menu}/delete', 'MenuController@destroy');
...continues
```

So from that you can probably see that I have multiple controllers that handle this for the admin, however, if a user logs in, they should be able to view the menus against the wedding, which I can stack with **@auth** tags, and seperate it out like that, however I'm afraid I'm going to end up with a **web.php** that looks like the following:

```
# WEDDING HANDLING
Route::get('/admin/weddings', 'WeddingController@index');
Route::get('/weddings', 'WeddingController@index');
...continues
```

Hopefully from my demo you can see what I'm asking.

**tl;dr:** How would you go about seperating User/Management areas without duplicating a ton of code.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you dread web.php ending up looking like? Why would you need to call `Route::get('/admin/weddings', 'WeddingController@index');` twice for example?

Comment: @danronmoon - Sorry, updated my post. I didn't know if it was bad practice to refer 2 paths to the same controller/action pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are almost adhering to the *CRUD/REST convention*, an addition to *Adriano Marra*'s answer would be to also use *resource controllers*.

From Laravel [documentation about resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers):

> Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code.

---

#### Introducing Resource Controllers

In your use case your *resource* are the **weddings**, so you could rewrite your **web.php** routes as:

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('weddings', 'WeddingsController');
});
```

These lines would register such routes:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                           | Name             | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings                | weddings.index   | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | admin/weddings                | weddings.store   | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/create         | weddings.create  | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}      | weddings.show    | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/weddings/{wedding}      | weddings.update  | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | admin/weddings/{wedding}      | weddings.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/edit | weddings.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@edit    | web        |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

**NOTE:** There's a small difference as the `Route::resource(...)` method uses the plural resource name you provided to it (`weddings`) for all the seven routes, and the singular form for the parameter name (`wedding`).

You could then register the **menus** resource in the same way:

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('weddings', 'WeddingsController');

    // Personally, I would make 'menus' a top level resource but I will
    // stick to your routing example for the rest of the answer.
    Route::resource('weddings/{wedding}/menus', 'WeddingMenusController');
});
```

---

#### Named Group Resource Routes

Furthermore you could also register the frontend wedding controller as a resource

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('weddings', 'WeddingsController');
    Route::resource('weddings/{wedding}/menus', 'WeddingMenusController');
});

// This will map only two methods for this resource.
Route::resource('weddings', 'FrontendController')->only(['index', 'show']);
```

The routes registered by your application would be:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                        | Name             | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings                             | weddings.index   | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | admin/weddings                             | weddings.store   | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/create                      | weddings.create  | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | weddings.show    | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | weddings.update  | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | weddings.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/edit              | weddings.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@edit    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus             | menus.index      | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus             | menus.store      | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/create      | menus.create     | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | menus.show       | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | menus.update     | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | menus.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}/edit | menus.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@edit    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | weddings                                   | weddings.index   | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@index   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | weddings/{wedding}                         | weddings.show    | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@show    | web        |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

If you look close at the above table, you will notice that the name column has some duplicate values. This would create conflict when you need to reference these particular routes by name anywhere in your application.

So you could solve this by prefixing the admin group's named routes with a custom prefix:

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('weddings', 'WeddingsController');
    Route::resource('weddings/{wedding}/menus', 'WeddingMenusController');
});

// This will map only two methods for this resource.
Route::resource('weddings', 'FrontendController')->only(['index', 'show']);
```

This would solve any route conflict, as the administation routes has been correctly prefixed with `admin.` name:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                        | Name                   | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings                             | admin.weddings.index   | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | admin/weddings                             | admin.weddings.store   | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/create                      | admin.weddings.create  | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | admin.weddings.show    | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | admin.weddings.update  | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | admin.weddings.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/edit              | admin.weddings.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@edit    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus             | admin.menus.index      | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus             | admin.menus.store      | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/create      | admin.menus.create     | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | admin.menus.show       | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | admin.menus.update     | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | admin.menus.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}/edit | admin.menus.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\WeddingsController@edit    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | weddings                                   | weddings.index         | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@index   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | weddings/{wedding}                         | weddings.show          | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@show    | web        |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

---

#### Namespacing Groups

Finally, you could go further with optimizations with introduction of namespaces (useful if you start to have more and more controllers).

You can create a folder in you `app/Http/Controllers`, for example `Administration`, where you store all of your administrative controllers.

In the **web.php** file, you just have to tell Laravel that the admin prefixed route group should look for controllers in the newly created folder:

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Administration')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('weddings', 'WeddingsController');
    Route::resource('weddings/{wedding}/menus', 'WeddingMenusController');
});

// This will map only two methods for this resource.
Route::resource('weddings', 'FrontendController')->only(['index', 'show']);
```

This would lead to register these routes:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                        | Name                   | Action                                                         | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings                             | admin.weddings.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | admin/weddings                             | admin.weddings.store   | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/create                      | admin.weddings.create  | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | admin.weddings.show    | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | admin.weddings.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | admin/weddings/{wedding}                   | admin.weddings.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/edit              | admin.weddings.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@edit    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus             | admin.menus.index      | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus             | admin.menus.store      | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/create      | admin.menus.create     | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | admin.menus.show       | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | admin.menus.update     | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}      | admin.menus.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/weddings/{wedding}/menus/{menu}/edit | admin.menus.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\Administration\WeddingsController@edit    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | weddings                                   | weddings.index         | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@index                  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | weddings/{wedding}                         | weddings.show          | App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@show                   | web        |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Very standardize approach :) +1

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create different controllers just to handle the front-end, like: FrontEndMenuController@yourFunction

you could also separate your admin routes into a group with the prefix 'admin' instead of repeating it on all the routes:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/wedding/{wedding}/menus', 'MenuController@index');
   Route::get('/wedding/{wedding}/menu/create', 'MenuController@create');
   Route::get('/wedding/{wedding}/menu/{menu}', 'MenuController@show');
   Route::get('/wedding/{wedding}/menu/{menu}/edit', 'MenuController@edit');
});
```

And then have your front-end routes like that:

```
Route::get('/wedding/{wedding}/menu', 'FrontEndMenuController@index');
```

Comment: Didn't know about the Route prefixing, just implemented that now and it's a nice way of keeping the file readable, love it.

Comment: Glad to know I could help, btw, you can also implement other groups inside previous ones e.g. create a group 'wedding' inside the group 'admin'... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new FrontEndController, and route any front end pages to that controller.

```
Route::get('/admin/weddings', 'WeddingController@index');
Route::get('/weddings', 'FrontEndControllerController@showWeddings');
```

Then you can use middlewear to diferentiate and refactor any repeated code into the Wedding model and just call that.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, at least I'm not too far from the mark! Thanks, I'll do a bit more reading on middleware before I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do when i need to separate admin and front end routes

```
Route::group([
        'prefix'          => 'admin',
        'namespace'       => 'Admin', // assumed
        // 'as'           => 'admin.'  
        // 'middleware'   => 'admin.'  
    ], function () {

        Route::get('weddings', 'WeddingController@index');

        Route::group([
            'prefix'       => 'wedding',
        ], function () {
            // Wedding Management
            Route::get('{wedding}/show', 'WeddingController@show'); // Updated with /show in url otherwise it will overlap create

            Route::get('{wedding}/edit', 'WeddingController@edit');
            Route::put('{wedding}/edit', 'WeddingController@update');

            Route::delete('{wedding}/destroy', 'WeddingController@destroy');

            Route::get('create', 'WeddingController@create');
            Route::post('create', 'WeddingController@store');

            // Here you differentiate WeddingController and MenuController

            // Route::group([
            //    'middleware'       => 'only_applied_to_this_group',
            // ], function () {
                    // Menu Management
                    Route::get('{wedding}/menus', 'MenuController@index');
                    Route::get('{wedding}/menu/create', 'MenuController@create');
                    Route::get('{wedding}/menu/{menu}', 'MenuController@show');
                    Route::get('{wedding}/menu/{menu}/edit', 'MenuController@edit');

                    Route::post('{wedding}/menu/create', 'MenuController@store');
                    Route::put('{wedding}/menu/{menu}/edit', 'MenuController@update');
                    Route::delete('{wedding}/menu/{menu}/delete', 'MenuController@destroy')
            // });
        });
    });

    Route::group([
        'namespace'    => 'Front',
        'as'           => 'front.'
    ], function () {
        // Front-end Management
    });
```

I tried to make it more simplified for better routes understanding, i hope this works.